# Calcular número mínimo de permutações para ordenar

Tags: array, classificação, lógica

Recebi esta questão em um teste, e gostaria de saber que caminhos tomar.

Tenho um array de n inteiros distintos, A = [a0, a1, ..., an-1].
Posso permutar quaisquer dois elementos do array qualquer número de vezes. 
Como calcular o menor número de permutações necessárias para ordenar os elementos de maneira crescente?

Comment: Em alguma linguagem em especifico?

Comment: Em qualquer linguagem

Comment: Usando ponteiros resolve o seu problema

Answer (score 1):

Existem vários [algoritmos de ordenação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o), mas o principal entre eles é o **quick sort**.

Ele consiste em definir um dos elementos da lista como elemento pivô. No exemplo abaixo, é considerado o elemento 3 como pivô, sendo representado pelo risco preto. A finalidade é organizar todos os elementos que são inferiores ao pivô à sua esquerda e todos os que são superiores à sua direita. Assim, ao final, o elemento pivô já estará em sua posição final. Após, executa-se recursivamente a mesma lógica para os elementos à esquerda e para os elementos à direita, definindo novos elementos pivôs.

A lógica executada é a seguinte:

1. Verifica-se à direita do pivô, do final para o início, o primeiro elemento que seja inferior ao mesmo, permutando suas posições. No caso, o primeiro elemento inferior à 3 é o 1.
2. Verifica-se à esquerda do pivô, do início para o final, o primeiro elemento que seja superior ao mesmo, permutando suas posições. No caso, o primeiro elemento superior à 3 é o 5.
3. Repete-se a verificação do passo 1, encontrando o valor 2, permutando as posições novamente.
4. Repete-se a verificação do passo 2, encontrando o valor 4, permutando as posições novamente.
5. O elemento pivô estará em sua posição final, então repete-se o algoritmo para os vetores [1, 2] e [4, 5] separadamente, até o vetor estar completamente ordenado.

[image: Funcionamento do algoritmo Quick Sort]

#### *Quick Sort* em Python

```py
def quick_sort(vector):
  # Se o vetor tiver comprimento 1, terminou a ordenação:
  if len(vector) <= 1:
    return vector
  else:
    return quick_sort([x for x in vector[1:] if x < vector[0]]) + \ # Ordena o vetor a esquerda
           [vector[0]] + \                                          # Elemento pivô na posição final
           quick_sort([x for x in vector[1:] if x>=vector[0]])      # Ordena o vetor a direita
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/GVjG/0)</sup>

---

### Mínimo de permutações

Dado que a pergunta se originou de um teste/prova, acredito que o conhecimento prévio sobre os algoritmos de ordenação era esperado, assim, para responder, posso tomar como referência que o *Quick Sort* já é o algoritmo mais eficiente e o que exige menos permutações durante a ordenação, com isso, basta que eu calcule o número de permutações que tal algoritmo fará para determinar o mínimo possível.

Considerando um vetor genérico, o pior caso acontece quando o pivô é o maior ou menor elemento e o vetor está previamente ordenado de forma inversa. Ou seja, o pior caso ocorre quando os sub-vetores são desbalanceados: um com tamanho `n-1` e outro 0, sendo `n` o tamanho do vetor. Portanto, o número de comparações e permutações feitas em cada sub-vetor será `n-1` para o vetor da esquerda e `0` da direita. Na segunda iteração, os vetores terão tamanhos `n-2` e 1, portanto haverá `n-2` comparações ao total. Assim continua até o vetor estar ordenado, portanto, o total de comparações/permutações será igual a:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O melhor caso ocorre quando o elemento pivô divide o vetor em tamanhos iguais, havendo `n/2` comparações em cada sub-vetor, portanto o total é igual à:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Fontes:**

- [Quicksort - Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)
- [Quicksort - UFMG](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~cunha/teaching/20121/aeds2/quicksort.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o **Anderson** referenciou anteriormente um algoritmo bem eficaz para organizar um array é o **QuickSort**. O algoritmo consiste em Fixar uma posição do array e comparar o valor referente à essa posição com as demais e quando chegamos na na última posição `n-1`, já não precisamos fazer nenhuma comparação.

**Importante:** o array começa da posição 0 e termina na posição n-1, ou seja, se declaramos um array de tamanho 5, não vamos percorrer a posição 5 do array pois ela não existe, vamos até a posição 4 (`n-1`)

Vou tentar escrever o algoritmo em português, mas abaixo se encontra o algoritmo em Java:

```
Inteiro  [5] vetor := {16, 7, -9, 4, 13};  
Inteiro auxiliar :=0;  
Inteiro i := 0;  
Inteiro b :=0;  

Para (i:=0 até vetor.tamanho-1) faça{  
---- Para (b:= i+1 até vetor.tamanho -2) faça {  
-------- Se ( vetor [ i ] > vetor [ i+1] ) {  
-------- auxiliar := vetor [ i ];  
-------- vetor [ i ] := vetor [ i+1 ];  
-------- vetor [ i+1] := auxiliar;  
-------- }  
----}  
}
```

Exemplo no Java:

[image: QuickSort no Java]

Espero ter ajudado...